# Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I get this error when trying to use `apt-get`:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is also true if you reboot? Maybe some old apt thread is locking the file, you need to find out which and kill it or just rebooting will do it.

Comment: yes, even after reboots im getting the same responses. Do you know how can I find which apt thread is locking the file?. Thank you!

Comment: [This procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) almost always fixes this problem, and when it doesn't, its output (the text from the Terminal) is sometimes useful. If you decide to do it, you can add this text to your question.

Comment: I would suggest one more thing that you may note when faced with this issue. Do check if your disk drives are mounted. If they are not, you may not be able to acquire the lock as the package installer will not be able to access the filesystem. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: You can use `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to find the process that owns the lock file (if empty, assume the lock is left over from a previous boot and can be `sudo rm`d), then consider doing a `sudo kill -9 <PID>` (get <PID> from `lsof` output.

Comment: This is old, but I'm noticing your original question doesn't indicate you are running this as root or via `sudo`.

Comment: This can be a sign that something else is installing or removing software and has locked the apt database while it performs the actions.

Comment: For me, rebooting did solve it.

Comment: I don't think much of any of the answers here. It might be better to find out which process has the lock and kill that process. See this for more info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858466

Comment: So this happens to me all the time and the solutions is simpler as check if you have Synaptic Package Installer open while trying install in terminal.

Comment: If the lock is caused by apt-daily.service, then try https://askubuntu.com/a/878982/288250

Comment: It was just the software updater.  But by RDP it is found in the Applications, Settings menu.  Once it came up and was stopped, then all was well.

Comment: restart fixed it for me

Comment: It happened right after reboot for me. There was a dkpg already running probably to auto-update software. I waited until it was done. Then I could install.

Comment: Running `sudo pkill apt-get` worked for me.

Comment: This happened to me, and it turned out that Ubuntu was waiting patiently in the background for me to go ahead with updates (Software update icon visible in the launcher bar). Once I did this and it completed, I was able to continue using apt-get without issue.

Comment: OK so I had the same problem BUT here's the deal: I didn't notice that the "'There are updates available', install, cancel, remind me later"-window was open in the background. So I closed it and then it worked.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 VM there is a process called unattended-update, which is runned by a process like `root       <pid>   <ppid>  0 15:58 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install`, which seems to run apt update every time I turn the machine on. Depending on the size of the update (which often corresponds to how long ago since I used that machine the last time), this can use from 1-10 minutes to complete. After that, the lock is freed for manual apt installs and updates. Try: `sudo ps aux|grep apt` or `sudo ps aux|grep unattended.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to check if some other program could be running system update or installing a program.

If you are using command line, check if an application like Software Center, Software Updater, Synaptic, Gdebi is running any update/installation. If that’s the case, 

If there is no such application running, please check all the open terminal windows and see if you are running an update or installing a program. If yes, wait for it to finish.If none of the above is happening, check which other process is running the apt command

Comment: If you've just started up your machine, I strongly recommend @poolie's answer below https://askubuntu.com/a/15440/1115972 .tl;dr WAIT a few minutes to let the auto-updater finish its work, then try again.

Comment: For me, waiting a few minutes solved the problem -- I'd been trying to `apt upgrade` just after boot.

Answer (score 955):

#### This should be used as last resort. If you use this carelessly you can end up with a broken system. Please try the [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/15436/44179) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/315791/44179) [first](https://askubuntu.com/a/878982/225694) before doing this.

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After that, try opening Synaptic again.

Comment: ok... but why happened this?

Comment: @jaime: probably apt-get (or some GUI frontend to it) was halted while executing, leaving apt in a locked state.

Comment: @AnwarShah no, there are other considerations before going around removing files of the system.

Comment: rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock; dpkg --configure -a:

Comment: Well its have some change.  sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I still get the same error!

Comment: @bouke....you are correct. I have faced something similar today for time being. I have given command to open Google Chrome and also "sudo ap-get update" command same time. After opening Google Chrome, lock becomes available.

Comment: I type sudo rm lock from it's directory and it remains there like the undead

Comment: Thank you. This should only be attempted when any `apt` and `dpkg` instance have been killed. In my case I interrupted the process so I had to manually remove the locks.

Comment: happened when I awoke a suspended vagrant box and the `up` failed. ran `reload` and got this error message when I tried to install a package, deleting the lock fixed it

Comment: Argh, please no, never recommend removing the lock files! This is a sure way to damage your package managers databases. :/ The presence of this files does not indicate that a process is locking them. Some time ago I added an entry to the dpkg FAQ explaining this given that the Internet seems to be filled with incorrect advice: https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F. In addition we have improved both dpkg and apt to print a more detailed error message with the process holding the lock and apt now waits by default for the lock to be released.

Comment: running `sudo apt update` solved my same issue.

Answer (score 758):

(Note: my original answer was extensively edited by Guillem Jover, the [primary `dpkg` developer](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/).)

I see pretty much all the answers recommend deleting the lock. That **must** never be done, it is always preferable to kill `dpkg` (which is supposed to be resilient against that kind of event), than to even think about removing its lock file (where its presence does not indicate the lock being held). The locks are acquired when a `dpkg` or an `apt` process is running, and are released (by the kernel if necessary) when the processes complete or are killed. Newer `dpkg` and `apt` versions will print the PID of the process holding the contended lock file, and `apt` now even waits by default for the locks to be released. This is covered in the [dpkg FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F).

If you try:

```
sudo fuser -vik -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

that will prompt to terminate any process currently holding these lock files, which, once killed will get the locks released. If you see an `apt-get` process or an `aptitude` process that looks stuck, killing them should be less harmful than when the packaging system is in the middle of a package installation. If the processes are really stuck and you have no other choice, you might need to kill them by passing `-KILL` instead of `-TERM`. You then need to finish any pending configuration so that `dpkg` can get those into a better state, and so that it can also integrate updates to its journal to the main status database.

Killing a `dpkg` process directly, if present, is in general not a great idea, because if `dpkg` is active, some maintainer script might be performing actions that are not resilient against abrupt termination (or crashes), but dpkg internally should be resilient to such abrupt terminations, and it's preferable to do that, than to remove any lock file, which has a way higher chance of damaging **both** the dpkg database and the filesystem.

Killing a frontend such as an `apt-get` or `aptitude` process, while not ideal, is in general much safer.

Comment: Also, I would kill dpkg. This worked for me, as it was trying to finish something it stared before the machine was stopped previously, and couldn't figure it out on his own.

Comment: @Link I don't think killing `dpkg` is a good idea, because usually `dpkg` is manipulating the package database directly, and this could cause corruption.

Comment: There was no need to kill `dpkg`. After killing the stuck `apt-get` process, `dpkg` went away automatically.

Comment: If killing dpkg can corrupt its database, dpkg was badly designed. Period.

Comment: for me, this resulted in an error `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` when running `sudo apt-get  dist-upgrade` again. Running the command then resolved the issue. I love Nix!

Comment: Note, `killall apt-get` does the same thing as your `ps`/`kill` combo.

Comment: Should I kill `aptd`?

Comment: Note that I found that I needed to run `sudo dkpg --configure -a` after killing the rogue apt process in order for things to return back to normal.

Comment: Easiest way to know the process which is doing trouble `ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep` then run sudo kill num eg `sudo kill 2304`

Comment: I experienced the same issue and in my case the problem was the ubuntu unattended upgrades. the same issue is talk about [here](https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu/issues/73#issuecomment-231679733). also you could also `apt remove unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: In my case it was automagically solved after second or third reboot, but not after the first one... o.O? Anyway, do try to complete processes (e.g., `sudo dpkg --configure -a`) and other harmless things (e.g., opening and closing software center, synaptic, software updates, etc.) before killing running processes. And try killing processes before force-deleting the lock, risking to break your system.

Comment: Don't `ps .. | grep ..` because it will match grep. Instead use `pgrep -f dpkg` and `pkill -f dpkg`

Comment: In the list of my processes I spotted a `usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.dayly install`. Figured I just had to give it some time and try again. It worked. I spared a process life and found  a peaceful solution to my problem.

Comment: How do I know processnumber? Plz more precisely..

Comment: @FaheemMitha similar to @Barry I suggest using `pgrep -a apt` instead.

Comment: @PabloBianchi There's no reason to use `pgrep` here. This answer isn't showing an automated or scripted approach, a human is involved. So `ps` or `pgrrp -a` are as good as each other.

Comment: @terdon You don't need to be using an automated or script to use `pgrep`. The difference isn't extremely important, but it's better because doesn't match grep (even better with [`-r`](https://askubuntu.com/a/185746/349837)). `ps`+`grep` is kind a hack, [`pgrep` is the right tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74190/209677).

Comment: Anyone: does ubuntu run apt briefly every time it boots?

Comment: @FaheemMitha What's the point of `grep [a]pt` ? it's the same as `grep [a]pt` in here.

Comment: @Shayan `[a]pt` is functionally equivalent to `apt`, but `apt` will be picked up in a grep for itself, while `[a]pt` won't.  It's just a little hack to filter that process out of the results.  Piping `ps` through `grep` isn't necessarily the best solution generally, but hey...

Comment: @mwfearnley ohh that makes so much sense, thanks very much, OP should add this to the answer.

Comment: did ps aux | grep [a]pt
two processes were running, 
waited some time, they automatically completed after some time

Comment: I appreciate your answer in contrast to the others, but I'd still appreciate if you could reword the "recommendation removing lock" part to not even suggest this might be appropriate at any stage of trying to fix such issue. Please see my comment on the question and the entry on the dpkg FAQ https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F, which I'm happy to further clarify if anything is unclear or similar.

Comment: @GuillemJover Thank you for the comment and the rewrite/edit. As `dpkg`'s maintainer, you are clearly better suited to answering this question than almost anyone else. I'll let others decide on the suitability of the edit. But since it's essentially a new answer, I'm a little surprised you didn't post it as such.

Comment: @FaheemMitha right, I considered that, and have already flagged almost any other answer that had as a reply to just remove the lock files as candidates for removal. Yours seemed like a good base on and improve, and also because it's the most correct one with the higher score. Which both help in getting further reach, as inappropriate advice to remove seems very spread, and all the answers here do not help. :/ I've also commented on the itsfoss.com article, etc. If people are more comfortable with a a new answer I could try that, but I'm not sure it would be very effective TBH.

Comment: @GuillemJover OK. I accepted the answer. Partly on faith, because I don't understand everything in the answer. But your comment is clearly compelling. Thank you for taking the time to write the answer.

Comment: Please let me know anything that is not clear from either the edited answer or from the FAQ, so that we can improve it for other people too, as I might be too close to realize what's obvious or not. And thanks for accepting it!

Comment: @GuillemJover Given that you have gone into so much detail, it, might be helpful to include a short example transcript for the earlier part of your answer, where you mention the usage of `sudo fuser -vik -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo dpkg --configure --pending`. It might not be obvious to many users how to use these commands. It's not immediately obvious to me. And in any case, AU is not considered to be a very hardcore technical forum.

Comment: For what it's worth, @GuillemJover, I am a relatively competent Linux user with >20 years of using Linux under my belt, and I wouldn't know what `fuser -vik -TERM` does beyond assuming it is somehow sending `TERM` signals to running processes. Some explanation would indeed be appreciated there.

Answer (score 238):

Remove your `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file and force package reconfiguration.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It should work after this.

Comment: these commands helped, but now when I tried to install again, got this reply : Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open. I think I would have to do like previous unlocking problem, but please tell me the exact keywords for command. I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: `sudo` - execute command as root, 
`rm` - remove file. 
Maybe try `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Comment: This is not a good suggestion: blindly removing the lock may corrupt dpkg's state.

Comment: Why won´t it fix itself nowadays?

Comment: This worked for me. The aws above didn't.

Comment: Can confirm what poolie said. It has corrupted the lock state by making one of the files inparsable. It told me would would get an error when parsing `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006`. I removed the file in question with `rm`, reran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and all appears to be working as expected again.

Comment: This worked the cleanest for me.

Comment: Only this one worked for me. It seems it's important to reconfigure packages.

Comment: Needed to do `killall aptd` first, how I found out - https://askubuntu.com/a/15445/277898

Answer (score 122):

The most likely way to hit this is:

- boot Ubuntu
- start a terminal
- type `sudo apt-get install whatever`

and the command-line `apt` overlaps with `update-manager` automatically polling.

*So if you try again in a few minutes that should fix it.*

Comment: Great hint in contrast to the half-dozen replies suggesting to just remove the file ;-) I randomly ran in the issue and most likely this is it!

Comment: Safe enough, had to wait a little before `sudo apt-get install` could work.

Comment: Well This is not working always, yes I have used reboot many times.  If it's not suitable try this http://askubuntu.com/a/315791/378845 before you remove locks

Comment: @menuka, why not just let it finish.

Comment: @poolie Because there are other constraints which are stopping the process from finishing

Comment: apt-get itself does not work at all. Typing your solution, error says E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: I'm not suggesting you type anything. I'm suggesting you wait a few minutes then try again. If that doesn't fix it there's a different problem, which is possible. But most people just need to wait.

Comment: you may combine this with executing *ps aux | grep apt* to see if something is changing or monitoring with system monitor before killing anything...

Comment: with `install whatever` you need new package or do install then remove, just change to reinstall so that can use existing package, maybe `sudo apt reinstall npm` or curl, or other small package

Answer (score 112):

You will get this message if you forget to use `sudo` when executing an apt command.

Otherwise this is a sign that something else is installing or removing software and has locked the apt database while it performs the actions. The programs that can do this are:

- The Software Center
- The Update Manager
- The apt link installer (I think this now goes through SC)
- The apt-get or aptitude command line utilities.
- The Synaptic Package Manager

**IMPORTANT: only try the below as a last resort since it can crash your system. First try killing any running instance of `apt` or `aptitude` as described in [Faheem's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/315791/85695).**

You can force the lock off by removing the file, but **it's not recommended without first closing the program that's holding the lock safely**, since you could cause corruption or interrupt an installation (bad). The command provided by João should close the program that holds the lock and then remove the lock but won't protect you from install interruption:

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

And the same command can be used for the apt cache lock:

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: I was updating my software when I got the error message.

Comment: This crashed for me-

Comment: `sudo fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` directly rebooted my computer. `apt-get` is now unlocked.

Comment: This crashed my entire server.

Comment: Killing apt or dpkg half way through is not a great idea.

Comment: This crashed my os

Comment: Kubuntu crashes during login after doing this.

Comment: If you can't log in, you can reboot in recovery mode. Choose the option to fix DPKGs.

Comment: You won't get `resource temporarily unavailable` if you run without it without `sudo`, you'll get `permission denied`.

Comment: The OP question says, "..is another process using it?" When you forget to `sudo` it, the message reads differently. It says, "...are you root?"

Comment: Don't use this command, It will crash your PC, if you already tried, restart won't help you. Just shut down the PC and start.

Comment: WARNING: this will cause DATA LOSS, because it is instantly rebooting  without any `SIGKILL`. It can damage databases and hard-drive. It will reboot as ROOT, this is also very bad, as `ecryptfs` will FAIL to decrypt home data's at next reboot!!! CAUTION GUYS!! As this answer is in top google for this query, an edit should be made.

Comment: And this can also make your wifi card off usage at next reboot. Depending the usage, if you were using ssh, you just kicked yourself OUT. You then need physical access to reboot...... WARNING!!!!

Comment: I didn't have any apt running and it still disabled all my services, I had to reboot. I should've just delete the lock file.

Comment: For me, it was just because Synaptic manager window was left open. The moment I closed it, the issue on the terminal got resolved.

Answer (score 53):

Only one program can hold the lock. Make sure that you are not running aptitude, synaptic or adept. Close the program and run it again it should work.You may either have synaptic open, or have another terminal window open running apt-get, or have the update manager running.Check it and see if any of those are running,if any of them is running close it and try again.

Try this command in terminal to find what is running

```
ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
```

**Note:**
If that doesn’t print anything, type the following in terminal to remove the lock

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Now you can install any Packages.

Comment: Deleting the lock file is, what I would consider, a dangerous thing to do. If another process is locking for a valid reason - and you remove that lock file and force an install with what you were doing prior - you could seriously, in a negative way, affect your system.

Comment: That's why i have given that in Note.If all the above fails the only way is to remove the lock.It wont cause any problem as long as dpkg and apt-get/aptitude processes aren't running

Comment: `pgrep -f 'apt|adept|dpkg'` is a lot shorter.

Comment: Thx! this works. pgrep -f 'apt|adept|dpkg'  and then sudo skill (number) , kill all number and then install works!

Comment: @Barry that would match with the whole path+process. I think `pgrep -a 'apt|adept|dpkg'` is a better shorter equivalent.

Comment: @PabloBianchi   `-f` has edge-cases but `-fa` if you like since pgrep without `-f` will have false negatives because the process name isn't always the same as argv[0]. pgrep really needs an option to grep the basename of argv[0] and the basename of the process name (which can be set to something else in some forms of `exec*()`).

Comment: @dhchdhd Please file an issue on [`pgrep` bug tracker](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to run the command while the GUI software updater was already doing its thing.

Answer (score 53):

So far the best way to get it working without breaking a possible background running installation ( as it could happen by removing the lock file), is stopping the service using apt:

Error:

```
# sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`
```

Solution:

```
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
```

After upgrading the system I suggest re-enabling it, as the bug locking it could be fixed with the upgrade.

`sudo systemctl start apt-daily.timer`

I haven't verified this error gets fixed after upgrading. I'll add a new comment once I have that verified

Comment: After upgrading the system and starting the apt-daily.timer service again I'm not facing this issue so far.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest method compared to all those higher voted answers above. It worked in my case flawlessly,  thank you!

Comment: This worked flawlessly on 17.10 as well

Comment: Worked on 17.10 +1

Comment: Working fine in 18.04. :)

Comment: The solution helped me to resolve a similar error: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Answer (score 36):

First of all we should check what process created the lock file using `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

or in another situation where `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` is problematic:

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

The output will be close to something like:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
apt-get   12127 root   4uW  REG  252,1        0    86   /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Then we should check what the commad is doing, we can find it out using `ps`, `pgrep` etc; the command is `apt-get` so I run:

```
pgrep apt-get -a
```

The `-a` switch lists the full command for me, in my case it's:

```
 pgrep -a apt-get
 12127 apt-get update
```

we can see that it's running `update` subcommand, I could run something like this too:

```
ps -f 12127
```

which produces:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root     12127 12126  0 09:39 pts/0    S+     0:00 apt-get update
```

In this case I would wait for some minute for resource to be freed and if after 2 or 3 minute problem still exist or the command was something that I didn't care about or was not harmful for system (like this `apt-get update`) I send a `SIGTERM` to the process:

```
sudo kill -15 12127
```

It should do the work, If it didn't I'm going to send `SIGINT` this time (It's like pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>):

```
sudo kill -2 12127
```

If it didn't work too, we should send an `SIGHUP` (`kill -1`), and finally if nothing works I simply kill the process:

```
sudo kill -9 12127
```

or

```
sudo pkill -9 apt-get
```

Then I remove busy resources:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Comment: One small thing is that `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` rather than `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` is the file in the question.

Comment: Thank the root gods that someone finally mentions `pgrep` and `pkill`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: if a install or upgrade caused this a `dpkg --configure -a` might be needed as well

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 23):

This error **may** be caused by the Update Manager trying to automatically refresh the list of packages in background, usually right after your login, thus locking the  directory.

In this case just wait few seconds (or more, if your last update was long ago) for it to complete or launch Update Manager to check the status.

Comment: I had this right after installing Ubuntu 16.04. Turns out that there was a background process in the Ubuntu Software Center that was waiting for me to manually install some updates.

Comment: Ditto after a fresh install of 16.04. It too much longer than "a few seconds" in my case (I had time to read this whole Q&A page!) but after refreshing `ps` a few times I could see `dpkg` was updating a whole load of stuff and I waited patiently for it all to finish. I then ran **Software Updater** until everything was up-to-date before trying to install anything new.

Answer (score 19):

Don't be so fast to remove something, it may totally damage your system; rather wait until the currently installing or uninstalling program finishes its task and after that you will get access. If you think that there is nothing currently installing or uninstalling, then just reboot your system with the command `sudo reboot`.

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer. Could you move this instead as a comment to the answer it was responding to?

Comment: @jvriesem I think this is a very important answer, because the point he's making is what is missing from many other answers!

Comment: @jvriesem This is usually the correct answer. I run into this problem quite often with my linux containers when I don't use them a long time. Just wait. Yes it may be a while. But let it do its job before going in and disrupting things.

Comment: This should be the first thing to try. This answer most of the time fixes the problem. I had it maybe 4-5 times yet, and a reboot always solved it.

Answer (score 11):

If you have security updates set to auto-install this will happen frequently. I literally wait 30 seconds and it fixes the issue. Just throwing this out there in case anyone else encounters this issue.

Comment: Depending on how long the distro has been booted, it could be as long as a half hour. But it's probably ideal to let your distro finish its job before disrupting things.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to wait for several minutes for the lock to be released  (looks like `apt` used to hold it). This all happened right after system boot.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this issue numerous times. For me, it was almost always caused by apt-get or some GUI that called it getting hung for some reason. I had to kill it which left various locks in place.

The other answers bring up very good points about making sure no updates are currently running before doing anything drastic like removing lock files. However, once you are sure that's not the case, the following usually works for me. I got it by reading many answers to questions like this one.

While most or all of this is presented in the other answers, this distills the fix down to a few commands.

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo fuser -vki /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo fuser -vki /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Use for unlocking the package system after an update of some kind crashed or terminated without finishing in some other way.  These commands should be run in the order presented.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 19.10 there may also be /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this answer anywhere above but on Ubuntu 16.04, I encountered this problem as well.  The cause was the time on my computer was set into the **future**.  (This is because I'm on a Windows+Ubuntu dual boot system and I guess I have messed up local time vs UTC time.)

One odd thing was that the locked file's date and time was the exact date and time that I ran the program.

I then used "fuser" as described in earlier posts and apt worked, but I was getting complaints about needing to run `dpkg -a -reconfigure`.  When I did that, I got errors like:

```
newline in field name #padding
```

in files like '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0003'.

All of this was very strange as I've never seen it before.  So, I thought these were symptoms and changed my data and time manually.  I knew there was a problem with the date/time when I logged in, but was ignoring it.  (Previously, it was setting it automatically via the Internet and NTP).

Then, all of the above problems were fixed...  Hopefully, this helps someone else!  The most notable symptom is perhaps the date/time of the lock file being the exact date/time that you are trying to run the command.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, X crashed while `apt-get` was still removing old kernels. I used the System Monitor to confirm it was still running and not stuck. Everything was fine once the process finished.

Answer (score 3):

Check the Launcher to see if `Software Updater` is running. If so maximize it and have a look at what it is doing. If it is still checking, then wait for it to complete. When it completes it might tell you the software is up-to-date so close the app. If it says there are updates available, either do the update or click "remind me later". After this this app closes you can go back to using `apt-get` or `apt`.

If `Software Updater` is not running, just use the Dash to invoke it and the wait for completion and then decide if you want to update or click "remind me later". After this this app closes you can go back to using `apt-get` or `apt`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo killall -9 apt && sudo killall -9 dpkg
```

Use at your own risk

Comment: Perhaps not that bad to apply killall? At least this question's duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari has an answer which recommends the same. In my case, its output was `apt: no process found`, and afterwards, a `sudo apt-get ...` command reacted differently, saying `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` which is part of the highest voted answers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was getting the same message by not realizing I had switched to root user and was trying **sudo** apt-get. Once I realized this I just ran apt-get, and it worked. Silly, but it might still explain the error for some.

Comment: That's not the cause of the issue, since you *can* run `sudo` as root (and even if you couldn't, it wouldn't produce this error message). More likely what happened was that the other process finished while you were writing the next command.

Comment: Sometimes it does produce that same error message.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, after:

1. Open Firefox.
2. Open terminal

I typed

```
sudo apt update
sudp apt upgrade
```

then I get that problems

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I fixed that, running the command that was showed me after run `sudo apt update`

```
apt list --upgradable
```

This command will show you a list of programs in my case only Firefox, I closed Firefox, then could ran the command again without problems.

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who are interested in proactively preventing this bug in their scripts, I found that the -q flag on `apt upgrade -yq` was causing this issue for me. During the upgrade process I guess it would occasionally give me warnings (something along the lines of updating the desktop, would I like to continue), and if these warnings were suppressed, then I guess that causes apt to not unlock the files it was protecting and it got stuck.

Admittedly, I had trouble reproducing this error 100% of the time, **but eliminating that -q option completely fixed the issue for me**.

Answer (score 1):

Like most everyone else I waited for the lock to be removed. After 30 minutes I gave up and hard booted to a different distribution. From there I used the internet for some research which landed me here.

It turns out `unattended-upgrades.service` is running. I found that be rebooting into the broken system and running:

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl disable unattended-upgrades.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo shutdown -r # Note it will take a couple minutes to reboot
```

allowed me to get the broken system working again for:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
```

However it didn't fix the kept-back packages and impossible situation reported by `apt` in the first place. It would appear this was causing `apt` to lock up at boot in the first place.

Comment: Find  unattended-upgrade defaults in APT conf e.g. `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unat- tended-upgrades`

Comment: Removing the below files, solved my issue. 

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

Please refer https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-could-not-get-lock-error-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the top upvoted answers on this page and they always worked for me without exception, however I discovered an easier way to solve this problem. First some theory. What happens before a user gets this error message?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

`/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is locked so the terminal temporarily can't use it, but what process is it locked by? This depends on the circumstances. If you have booted the computer a few minutes ago it is probably locked by the Software app. Try closing the terminal and launching the Software app. If the Software app is indeed locking `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` it will show a screen that says `Software catalog is being downloaded` when you open it.

[image]

After the Software app finishes updating it will show a popup notification message, and another **Software Updater** window may also appear as show below. Otherwise the Software app will remove its own lock without the user needing to run any commands in the terminal.

[image]

After it has finished updating the software the Software Updater will remove its own lock without the user needing to run any commands in the terminal.

Another case where this answer is useful is in a VM when booting an Ubuntu guest OS that has been inactive for a while. Normally the Ubuntu guest OS starts to update almost immediately. The updating process frequently locks out commands that require installing, removing or updating software until it finishes. Open the Software app, let it finish running and install whatever updates that you want it to install. The Software app will remove its own lock when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot and it will auto fix the problem.
This is your installation interrupted accidently.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this only in the hope that it might be connected, I have not tested this solution. If deleting the lock files does not help, and if it is not even recommended according to the accepted answer, it might help how the similar problem [dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process/1303640#1303640) could be solved using the recovery mode with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in the root shell prompt.

#### Copy from there:

I had removed the lock files, and there was no PID running, yet, whenever I executed `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, the shell was stuck at one of the previously locked "apt" tasks that I had force-closed by closing the terminal in the end.
I also killed the apt processes using `sudo killall apt apt-get`. The stuck apt task in my case was "`Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic)`".

Solution in my case:

- Boot in recovery mode.
- In the recovery menu, choose "root" in order to "Drop to root shell prompt".
- Press Enter.
- Type `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
- Go on with what you were about to do, it should work now, and / or just reboot.

Please see screenshots and detailed explanation (e.g. how to get the recovery mode at start) at the answer of [docker ps stuck … docker install also just hangs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236208/docker-ps-stuck-docker-install-also-just-hangs/1299837#1299837).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Runtime environment:
   Operation System: Ubuntu 18.04
   Computer:Dell Precision 5510